# Is $A(x) = y^{T}*x \leq b$ a closed mapping?

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to prove whether or not the point to set mapping on $E^n$ defined by:

$A(x) = \{y: y^Tx \leq b\}$,

where b is a fixed constant is a closed mapping.
A(x) is an iterative algorithm defined by $x_{k+1} = A(x_k), y = A(x_k)$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by closed mapping? What topology is on the power set of $E^n$?

Comment: $E^n$ is the n dimensional euclidean space. closed mapping as in the set that is spanned by Y from the mapping of a point x $\in$ X to the set Y through A(x) is a closed set.

Comment: A(x) is an iterative algorithm that takes the argument x, and produced a set of outputs, from which one is selected as the next input. $x_{k+1} \in A(x_k), y = A(x_k)$.

Answer (score 0):

For each $x$ and $b$ the set $A(x)$ is closed because a mapping $m:E^n\to E$, $t\mapsto y^Tx$ is continuous, $A(x)=m^{-1}(-\infty,b]$, and the set $(-\infty,b]$ is closed in $E$.